# Wrong packet per second value on vlan interface tcp traffic

Tags: networking, server, vlan

I get wrong results when I check pps value on sub interface (vlan interface), on Ubuntu 22.04, but I know other versions have this problem as well.

I send traffic 100mbps to my test machine. On standard interface eth0  I have approx 9k pps, when I receive 100mbps by vlan tagged interface eth0.20 I have 700pps.

The problem occurs with TCP traffic, UDP is ok.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

I check the values here /sys/class/net/$int/statistics/tx_packets